# Login link Wordpress wont work because of rewriterule in own .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex i.php index.php index.html
Redirect 301 /tx http://www.tx-website.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(nyhet)/([^/]+)/?$ /?s=$1&n=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?s=$1_$2 [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.no/404
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.website.no/404
```

This works fine!

But it dont work when I try to login to Wordpress through the link:

www.website.no/blog/wp-admin/index.php

Then I'm send to the 404 site.

What is wrong? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rules in top of your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
```

It will preserve paths for wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes, and allow php files.